# Rose Hip Substitution

Tags: recipe, substitution

I found a recipe for a blonde ale that calls for dried rose hips and dried rose buds. I'm having trouble finding these ingredients and am wondering if there are any good substitutes.

The recipe specifically calls for 1 tsp of rose hips and 1 tbsp of rose buds to be added at 20 min into the boil and at the end of the boil, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head I'd say hibiscus flowers could be easier to find and could add something akin to rose hips, which are described as "[fragrant and floral, citrusy and sour](http://www.silive.com/entertainment/dining/index.ssf/2011/06/use_rosehips_from_the_garden_t.html)". Hibiscus certainly could get you in the ballpark, as it has a "[tart, cranberry-like flavor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibiscus_tea)". Maybe throw in some flowery hops like East Kent Goldings to make up the "floral" component of the rose hips.

Look for dried hibiscus in any Latin-American grocery stores or markets near you, where it might be referred to as "jamaica," which is it's Spanish name I believe.

Comment: That sounds good. I'll give it a try and post how it goes.